# Question on riemann sum $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n})$ NBHM $2005$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

Question is to evaluate  $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n})$$

I see that this is to be done with Riemann sums..

I first partition $[0,1]$ as $\{0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},\dots,1\}$

Now, Riemann Sum is defined as $\sum_{i=1}^n f(x^*_i)|(x_i-x_{i-1})|$

So, here i would have

$$f(0).\frac{1}{n}+f(\frac{1}{n})\frac{1}{n}+f(\frac{2}{n})\frac{1}{n}+\dots+f(\frac{n-1}{n})\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}.\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(\frac{k}{n})$$

Or

$$f(\frac{1}{n})\frac{1}{n}+f(\frac{2}{n})\frac{1}{n}+\dots+f(1)\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n}.\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n})$$

I would get first case if i take $x^*_i=x_{i-1}$ and i would get second case if i take $x^*_i=x_i$

But I am afraid I would not get $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n})$$

I am actually confused..

Should the question be something like $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(\frac{k}{n})$$?

I am sure i am missing something..

Please help me to clear that.

Thank you

Comment: Can you just use $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^n f(\frac{k}{n}) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\frac{k}{n}) + \frac{1}{n}f(1)$?

Comment: @John : Yes Yes... This does makes sense :) :) but there might be some technical problem.. are you sure there would not be any such problem?

Comment: As long as $f$ is integrable, I don't think there would be any problem.

Comment: @John : May be you are correct... Thank you :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Is this NBHM PHD question?? Shouldn't f(x) be f'(x)???

Comment: @TattwamasiAmrutam It is just $f(x)$

Comment: where did you get the 2005 and 2013 NBHM phd questions? It is not on the site

Comment: I have taken print out long back $2005$ PAPER... i myself written that $2013$ exam so.... :D

Answer (score 2):

This is almost the definition of the Riemann integral. Therefore:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n} \right) = \int_0^1 f\left(x \right) dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter
if the sum goes up to
$n$ or $n-1$,
because the difference is
$\frac{f(1)}{n}$
which goes to zero as
$n \to \infty$.